# replacing the sigma signs in double countable summation

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, summation

For every sequence $\{a_{mn}\}$ where $a_{mn}≥0$ for all $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$, show that
 $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}a_{mn}=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{mn} $$
Through an example show that the condition “$a_{mn}≥0$” is essential and can’t be removed in general.

I proved the first part by exchanging one summation to an integral on N and by counting measure, but I don't find an example to show that the condition is essential.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! For some basic information about writing math here see 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 4):

Consider
\begin{array}{5}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots
\\
-1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & \cdots
\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots
\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots
\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots
\end{array}

If you add the columns first, then the rows, you get zero.

If you add the rows first, then you get "$\infty-\infty$" which isn't well defined.

The point is that when all the entries are nonnegative, then if any row/column has a divergent sum, then the double sum will also be divergent. If you don't have this nonnegativity condition then you can get cancellations when you add one way, but not the other.

Comment: It is also possible for both sums to exist as finite numbers and still have different values.